# Easy way to retrieve userId of a User that is not active yet?

Tags: docusignapi

I provision a user through the docusign api and the new user is not active yet (status=ActivationSent).  Now for whatever reason I want to deprovision this user.  The deprovision API requires a userId. My question is finding this userId efficiently.

I tried getting the user information using the endpoint
`/accounts/{accountId}/users?email={emailAddress}` but it returned a 400 with error code `USER_LACKS_MEMBERSHIP`.

I saw I can get a list of all users for an account using the end point `/accounts/{accountId}/users` and then finding the user and userId I'm interested in.  Is there a more efficient way to get the userId in this scenario than querying all users?

Also is there a corresponding SOAP call to get all of the users for an account? I can't find it in the SOAP documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, the method that you describe (retrieving a list of all users and then iterating through the list to find the user you want to deprovision) is the only way to find/retrieve the **User Id** of a user that has **userStatus** = "Activation Sent".  Unfortunately (as you've discovered), the `/accounts/{accountId}/users?email={emailAddress}` is only successful for 'active' users.

That being said though -- when you provision a User via the REST API (`POST /accounts/{accountId}/users`), a successful Response should contain the **userId** for the new user.  Perhaps your application can store the **userId** that's received in the response each time a new user is provisioned, and then you can subsequently use that **userId** value to deprovision a user if/when necessary.

I'm not very familiar with the SOAP API, but I don't see a "get all Users" operation in the DocuSign SOAP API Guide.  I'd expect that type of operation to be part of the "Account Management Service API", but I'm not seeing it there.